# how to write into excel file without dataframe using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

If my dataframe is empty then I simply need to create empty excel file and write in it `"There is no data for selected timeframe "`

```
folder_list = ['San Diego', 'Vista']
if not df.empty:
    # if daraframe is not empty then do this:
    for location, d in df.groupby('OfficeLocation'):
        for folder in folder_list:
            if folder == location: 
                writer=pd.ExcelWriter(f'\\\\my\username\Documents\Python\Split DataFrame by Multiple dataframes\{folder}\{location}.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')                  
            else: 
                print('df is empty')
            writer.save()
# if dataframe is empty I need to create empty excel file and wirte in cell A1 "There is no data for seleted timeframe"
else:
    for folder in folder_list:
        # this creates empty file with sheet name 'Sheet1'
        writer=pd.ExcelWriter(f'\\\\my\username\Documents\Python\Split DataFrame by Multiple dataframes\{folder}\{folder}.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter') 
        wb = writer.book
        ws = writer.sheets['Sheet1'] # this gives me an error
        writer.save()
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\my\username\Documents\Python\Split DataFrame by Multiple dataframes\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 41, in <module>
    ws = writer.sheets['Sheet1'] # this gives me an error
KeyError: 'Sheet1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be adding a new sheet instead:

```
for folder in folder_list:
    # this creates empty file with sheet name 'Sheet1'
    writer=pd.ExcelWriter(f'\\\\my\username\Documents\Python\Split DataFrame by Multiple dataframes\{folder}\{folder}.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') 
    wb = writer.book
    ws = wb.add_worksheet() # change to this
    writer.save()
```

See relevant documentation here: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#add_worksheet

If you were to user the default `openpyxl` engine, then the respective method is:

```
ws = wb.create_sheet()
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gives an error: `'Workbook' object has no attribute 'create_sheet'`

Comment: Are you committed to using `xlsxwriter` as the engine? I'm using `openpyxl` and this method works (`openpyxl` is the default engine used by `pandas` if you don't designate an `engine`).

Comment: I believe for `xlsxwriter` the equivalent is `.add_worksheet()`.  I'll edit the answer shortly

Comment: Yes. That is correct. `.add_worksheet()` is what I needed. Thank you. So in a future what is the best engine to use?` xlsxwriter` or `openpyxl`?

Comment: That's up to your preference.  I only asked because I wasn't familiar with `xlsxwriter`, but either one should suffice as long as you are comfortable with it.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't simply create it in the same loop like this.

```py
folder_list = ['San Diego', 'Vista']

# if daraframe is not empty then do this:
for location, d in df.groupby('OfficeLocation'):
    for folder in folder_list:
        if folder == location:
           if not df.empty: 
                writer=pd.ExcelWriter(f'\\\\my\username\Documents\Python\Split DataFrame by Multiple dataframes\{folder}\{location}.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')                  
            else:
                writer=pd.ExcelWriter(f'\\\\my\username\Documents\Python\Split DataFrame by Multiple dataframes\{folder}\{folder}.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter') 
                df_empty = pd.DataFrame({"There is no data for seleted timeframe" : []})
                df_empty.to_excel(writer, index=False)
                print('df is empty')
            writer.save()
```

But with your method you create a new file each times.

Comment: No, in a first part of a loop it will not generate file if dataframe is empty

Comment: I tried to put `if not df.empty:` in that location but it does not create any excel files. It works only if it at the beginning of the loop

Comment: Thank. It works as well, but I think you need to convert `df_empty to`  `DataFrame`: `df_empty = pd.DataFrame({'There is no data for seleted timeframe': []})`

Comment: @Oleg yes, code updated. Fell free to mark this awnser as accepted by ticking the check mark.